# Using Spotipy API to loop through a dataframe and search tracks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotify, spotipy

I've been working on a python script to web scrape Billboard.com and create a dataframe of both track titles and artist names. Heres the relevant code snippets:

```
#compiles top 100 artist names/tracks
song_list = pd.DataFrame(
    {
            'tracks': tracks,
            'artists': artists,
    })
#search for each song and add as track id
track =
artist =
track_id = sp.search(q='artist:' + artist + ' track:' + track, type='track')

#create the playlist with the set variables/add tracks
if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    sp.trace = False
    playlists = sp.user_playlist_create(username, playlist_name,
                                        description=playlist_description)
    results = sp.user_playlist_add_tracks(username, playlist_id, track_ids)
    print(results)
    pprint.pprint(playlists)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```

Im trying to search for every artist name + track title from the data frame and add it to the newly created playlist. I know I'd have to use a for loop, but im not sure how to use it in combination of spotipys search function. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the Pandas docs? You should find some useful information in there.

Comment: I did, but its just spotipys search function that i need help with in relation to the data frame. I can just use song_list.tracks to grab the tracks only but i dont know how to loop through it for the "tracks = " variable and make it work

Comment: `.apply()` is probably your best bet. I’m not sure though, I’ll come back to this tomorrow. Can you share a bit more of your program?

Comment: @AMC i appreciate you trying to help but i went on fiverr and paid a guy to check over the program since that was the fastest way. Wanted to say thanks for trying and im glad people like you try to help others here

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution, you should submit an answer here!